# Problems after upgrade from 17.10 to 18.04

Tags: boot, upgrade, 18.04, amdgpu

I tried to upgrade Kubunutu 17.10 to 18.04, and now I'm in trouble :(
Upgrade process ended with message

```
"Your system could be in an unusable state."
```

After reboot got blank screen. After some investigation I realized that problem is connected with graphics driver - when I add 'nomodeset' to grub options it boots, but is terribly slow. I am using Radeon R9 270x and amdgpu driver.
When I try to start without nomodeset (and also without quiet to see the messages) boot process seems to stop with following message:

```
fb: switching to amdgpudrmfb from VESA VGA
```

But in the background it continues, as I can see later in the syslog.
I tried to reinstall Xorg and libdrm-amdgpu1, but it didn't help.
Help please :)

Regards,
Piotr

UPDATE:
I discovered logs from upgrade in /var/log/dist-upgrade. Based on that I found that there were two problems. First it failed at installation of 'menu' package. Log says:

```
dpkg: error processing package menu (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for menu:
menu depends on libstdc++6 (>= 4.6); however:
Package libstdc++6:amd64 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package menu (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
```

Then on building kernel modules:

```
Processing triggers for linux-image-4.15.0-23-generic (4.15.0-23.25) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: 
'/var/crash/anbox-modules-dkms.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.15.0-23-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/anbox-modules-binder/9/build/make.log for more 
information.
```

The reason was some leftovers from anbox package existing in /var/lib/dkms. So I removed them and tried to reinstall complete kernel, and also reinstalled menu package. Both didn't help.

Comment: The reason for the failed upgrade is important, and you didn't tell us that. You just gave us the summary, which could have dozens of possible causes. Without more information, the best we can offer you is to fully backup your data, and then to clean-install 18.04.

Comment: I know... my fault, I didn't catch the message :(

Comment: But I have new update. I tried to boot in text mode (I mean pure text console, no framebuffer) and then start gui with startx. Xorg started and seems working properly. So it seems graphics driver as such works. So now the question is why it doesn't work when booting directly ?

Comment: Well, not exactly properly...3d acceleration doesn't work. glxinfo shows
   `OpenGL renderer string: llvmpipe (LLVM 6.0, 256 bits)`

Comment: Let's go back to that "dozens of possible causes", starting with incompatible packages mixed in from both versions of Ubuntu. If there were an easy answer, the system would have fixed it for you automatically. It *tried and failed* a set of common package-manager fixes, and then gave up...that's why you got the warning about "unusable state." Your system wasn't kidding.

Comment: Yes, I am not arguing with that, the question is how to recover. But I found something - see the update.

Comment: I gave up and reinstalled the system...

Comment: I think that was a wise decision.